# Using pandas query method to search for a datetime object

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to match a datetime object in a Pandas DataFrame with the query method.  Given this code

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

search_time = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 0, 0, 6)
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 0, 0, 0)],
              [1, 0, search_time]],
              columns=(['0', '1', 'datetime']))

df1 = df[df.datetime == search_time]
print(df1)
df2 = df.query('datetime == @search_time')
```

I want df1 and df2 to equal.  While df1 returns what I expect,

```
   0  1            datetime
1  1  0 2019-10-27 00:00:06
```

df2 raises `KeyError:  False`.  How can I correct the query syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is column name `datetime` collide with `datetime` object, solution is rename it, e.g. `datetime1`:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

search_time = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 0, 0, 6)

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 0, 0, 0)],
              [1, 0, search_time]],
              columns=(['0', '1', 'datetime1']))

df1 = df[df.datetime1 == search_time]
print(df1)
   0  1           datetime1
1  1  0 2019-10-27 00:00:06

df2 = df.query('datetime1 == @search_time')
print (df2)
   0  1           datetime1
1  1  0 2019-10-27 00:00:06
```

Also is possible rename it by `pandas`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 0, 0, 0)],
              [1, 0, search_time]],
              columns=(['0', '1', 'datetime']))

df2 = df.rename(columns={'datetime':'datetime1'}).query('datetime1 == @search_time')
print (df2)
   0  1           datetime1
1  1  0 2019-10-27 00:00:06
```